# Hibernate update query with innerjoin

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have the following MySQL update query with inner join:

```
 UPDATE Country AS c
 INNER JOIN  State s ON c.CountryID = s.CountryID
 INNER JOIN  City cy On s.StateID = cy.StateID
 SET  c.Active='Y', s.Active='Y',cy.Active='Y'
 WHERE  c.CountryID='12'
```

Here is my country mapping class

```
enter code here
@Entity
@Table(name = "Country")
public class Country {
public Country() {
}

@Id
@Column(name = "CountryID")
private String countryID;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country")
private Set<State> state = new HashSet<State>(0);

@Column(name = "CountryName")
private String countryName;
}
```

Mpping class for State

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "State")
 public class State {
public State() {
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "countryID", nullable = false)
private Country country;

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "StateID")
private String stateID;

@Column(name = "CountryID")
private String countryID;

@Column(name = "StateName")
private String stateName;
```

How can i write the same query in hibernatye language.can any one please help me.
i have tried a lot but i can't make it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the hibernate mapping of your 'Country' class?

Comment: Sure... Now Am Updated my Question with Country,State entity Class.

Comment: run the query once and select the ids of the entities then run the update query for each entity type with in(?) restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. HQL update queries can't have joins. See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> Some points to note:
>
> - [...]
> - No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query.

Comment: Yes. If you use SQL, you can do everything you could do with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can try to run a native-Query here. Just put your query with a @Query annotation, and then add nativeQuery=true at the end of the JPQL query to trigger the native-behaviour of the query.

Just keep in mind, you need to use all native-components for the native-query, so if an entity-class "Employee" is mapped to the table "employee" in the database, your query should read **Select name from employee** and not *Select name from Employee*.

Thanks.